# Spring 5 M2 - Reactive - Error while serializing ServerSentEvent

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

After upgrading from Spring 5.0.0 M1 to M2 this code has stopped working (I changed from `SseEvent` to `ServerSentEvent` class):

```
@RestController
public class StringsRestController {

    @GetMapping("/strings/sse/event")
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> sse() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100)).map(l -> {
            ServerSentEvent<String> event = ServerSentEvent.builder("foo").build();
            return event;
        }).take(2);
    }
```

The exception is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEvent and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:275) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
```

Comment: Could you create an issue on jira.spring.io with a sample application?

Comment: Done: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14748 Thank you Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressed in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14748

Returning `Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>` will imply `text/event-stream` serialization.